# Python - how do I remove last two lines of file, append lines, then replace those two lines I removed?

Tags: python, flask

I am developing with Flask, and am trying to create a page to create pages (as a sort of custom CMS). So the page will need to create its own @app.route decorator for a function that renders the page template when called in the app.py file. What I have come up with is to create three functions: `remove_last_two_lines` and `create_rendering_func` and `add_back_last_lines` (named for what they do). The `remove_last_two_lines` function and the `add_back_last_lines` function do exactly what I want. What I'm having trouble with is the `create_rendering_func`. It simply doesn't do anything, and doesn't raise an error. So I think the code is valid (and I am passing valid arguments), I just don't understand why it isn't working. The lines being overwritten are empty (that's why there is multiple newlines after the last line of the function). Thanks in advance!

```
def add_new_url(route, func_name, title, filename):
    lines = open(__file__, 'r').readlines()
    lines[-6] = '@app.route(\'%s\')' % route
    lines[-5] = '\ndef %s' % func_name
    lines[-4] = '\n\trender_template(\'filename\', the_title=%s)\n\n\n\n\n' % title
```

(This method sucks. Any tips on better methods appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the data to be inserted as a list of strings appended by newline characters (`\n`) and insert it into `lines` by slicing;

```
insert_lines = ["Hello\n", "World!\n"]
with open("my_text_file.txt") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    lines[-2:-2] = insert_lines
    myfile.seek(0)
    myfile.write(''.join(lines))
```

It necessitates reading the entire file into memory and creating a new file in memory before writing it, which could be a problem if your file is incredibly big, but it will insert "Hello" and "World!" before the second to last line of the file.